# Calculate age from date of birth(using calender) IN Jsf

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have a form in which I am using pimefaces calender component, now when user will select his date of birth using this component, I want to calculate his current age and need to put in a textbox. The age textbox should get automatically displayed as user will select his date of birth.

```
<h:outputLabel for="dobirth" value="Date of Birth (mu)" />
                <p:calendar value="#{patient.dob}" id="popupCal">
<p:ajax event="dateSelect" listener="#{patient.handleDateSelect}" />
                </p:calendar>
```

I am trying to calculate age by this way.

```
public void handleDateSelect(DateSelectEvent event) throws ParseException {

        System.out.println("inside get age");
        FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("d/M/yyyy");
        facesContext.addMessage(null,
                new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Date Selected",
                        format.format(event.getDate())));
        String dd=null;
        dd=format.format(event.getDate());
        System.out.println("date dd"+dd);
        Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM d, yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(dd);
        System.out.println("date+++++++++"+date);
        Calendar birth = new GregorianCalendar();
        Calendar today = new GregorianCalendar();
        int calculatedAge = 0;
        int factor = 0;

        Date currentDate = new Date(); // current date
        System.out.println("DOB" + dob);
        birth.setTime(date);
        System.out.println("set birth" + birth);
        today.setTime(currentDate);

        if (today.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) < birth.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR)) {
            factor = -1;

        }
        calculatedAge = today.get(Calendar.YEAR) - birth.get(Calendar.YEAR)
                + factor;
        System.out.println("age is " + calculatedAge);
    }
```

And I also need to display age as soon as user selects his birth using calender.

How can I display it in jsf 2.0 once I got my age.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this (add getter to `calculatedAge` property).

```
<h:form>
    <h:outputLabel for="dobirth" value="Date of Birth (mu)" />
    <p:calendar value="#{patient.dob}" id="popupCal">
        <p:ajax event="dateSelect" listener="#{patient.handleDateSelect}"      
               update="age" />
        </p:calendar>
    <h:outputText id="age" value="#{patient.calculatedAge}"/>
</h:form>
```

Comment: Prefixing the form ID in `update` is not necessary if it's inside the same form already, so that `prependId="false"` has no value here.

Comment: That doesn't matter, but I mean that your recommendation of using `update=":formID:age"` when not using `prependId="false"` is wrong.

Comment: @BalusC Well actually I mean something that in case that update="age" wont find the element he will need to check if the age id being prepened by some container...